# Import python dict with variable-length list items into pandas

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have the following dict:

```
d = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
     'col2': [[1,2], [4,3,2], []],
}
```

I would like a Pandas DataFrame something like:

```
idx, col1, col2
  0,  'a',  1
  1,  'a',  2
  2,  'b',  4
  3,  'b',  3
  4,  'b',  2
  5   'c',  nan
```

How can this be constructed? If I simply pass the dict, it does not unravel/repeat the list items in col2.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just going to have to construct it yourself. Here's one way:

```
col1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
col2 = [[1,2], [4,3,2], []]
col2_lens = map(len, col2)

# flatten col2
s2 = Series([eli for el in col2 for eli in (el or [nan])])

# replicate elements of col1 col2[i] times
s1 = Series(list(''.join(el * (col2_len or 1) for el, col2_len in zip(col1, col2_lens))))
concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
```

yielding

```
   0   1
0  a   1
1  a   2
2  b   4
3  b   3
4  b   2
5  c NaN
```

Here are `%%timeit`s for the 3 methods shown here

1.

```
%%timeit
col2_lens = map(len, col2)

# flatten col2
s2 = Series([eli for el in col2 for eli in (el or [nan])])

# replicate elements of col1 col2[i] times
s1 = Series(list(''.join(el * (col2_len or 1) for el, col2_len in zip(col1, col2_lens))))
concat([s1, s2], axis=1)

1000 loops, best of 3: 646 µs per loop
```

2.

```
%%timeit
df = DataFrame()
for a, b in zip(col1, col2):
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'col1': a, 'col2': b or [np.nan]})])

100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop
```

3.

```
%%timeit
frames = []
for a, b in zip(col1, col2):
    frames.append(pd.DataFrame({'col1': a, 'col2': b or [np.nan]}))
df = pd.concat(frames)

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.58 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think you can just use `zip(*izip_longest(*d['col2'], fillvalue=None))` (or very similar to sort it ready prior to being made to a DF)

Comment: Hmm, actually your algorithm is not correct. Try it with: `col1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']` and `col2 = [[1,2], [4,3,2], [], [5]]`. It gives incorrect result for the output DataFrame.

Comment: Yup, and now it's even faster :)